# How do I recover an unsaved, word document downloaded from an email program?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office-for-mac

I downloaded an essay for editing earlier today, worked on it for roughly four hours, and the program crashed.  Many changes have been made since the download.

I haven't once saved the document so it's in the temporary files. Is there a way to recover the file with the saved changes?

Comment: Did you download the file to a folder on your Desktop (or somewhere else)? Word **should** have created a temporary file, it should also ask you to restore it if you start it again.

Comment: Also, see if you can find it here: `/Users/username/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office version AutoRecovery/Autorecovery save of filename`

Comment: I opened the temporary file directly from word, so the file was not on the desktop, but the temporary file folder. I believe word doesn't save if it's in that file?

Comment: There is an autorecovery file saved at 12:36. I assume this means that if I force quit word, I'll be able to recover it?

Comment: I don't know when you last opened/quit Word and what time you have. But yes, I'd try that (and maybe make a copy of the autorecovery file first). I just posted this as an answer, maybe it works.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't save the temp file because the program had crashed, but I did recover my file. I very much appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Office for Mac should save autorecovery files at `/Users/username/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office version AutoRecovery/Autorecovery save of filename`.

If Word is still running or hanging you need to quit it before trying to open the autorecovered file.

And that all being said, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> a bit more often! It's Word for Mac, after all.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem: opened a Word document from within Entourage, edited the document for a while and saved it with a new filename. ( while not paying attention to the directory name ..)

Afterwards I couldn't find it.. Word's File -> Open Recent -> menu option did not show it as one of the files I had recently opened. Oops, slight panic.

I realised it probably stored it in Entourage's download directory, and indeed it was located there. So in case you're using Entourage for your email check:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/Outlook Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/52856277910/how-to-find-word-auto-recovery-files-in-osx) I found the autorecovery files in:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Office 2011 AutoRecovery
```

Answer (score 0):

In Word for Mac 2011, if you hit save without specifying the directory, the file will be in the Outlook Temp folder. The easy way to get there is click File>Open, click whatever folder is shown, that will bring up a list including "Recent Places", and Outlook Temp will be listed... Your file will be in that folder.